# ptr-record in Bind9

Tags: bind, ptr-record

I have att small business internet and trying to avoid paying them 50 bucks to make ptr-records as I need them. I am pretty sure this is corrrect, though it seems like they might have a block or some sort of override. Though I might just be completely doing it wrong as well.

````
193.252.76.in-addr.arpa. IN SOA **********.com mail.**************.com. (

        2011071006   ;Serial
        3600         ;Refresh
        1800         ;Retry
        604800       ;Expire
        86400        ;Minimum TTL

 )

233 IN PTR dns.**************.com
234 IN PTR mail.************.com
235 IN PTR **************.com
236 IN PTR game.************.com```
````

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: You should not obfuscate the domain, as PTR records are public information anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the `76.252.193.232/29` has probably been delegated to you

```
NetRange:       76.252.193.232 - 76.252.193.239
CIDR:           76.252.193.232/29
Customer:       Private Customer - AT&T Internet Services (C07084288)
```

the control over its reverse DNS isn't delegated to your DNS server (sic):

```
193.252.76.in-addr.arpa. IN  SOA  ns1.swbell.net. rm-hostmaster.ems.att.com. 
                                  ( 4 86400 10000 604800 86400 )
193.252.76.in-addr.arpa. IN  NS   ns3.sbcglobal.net.
193.252.76.in-addr.arpa. IN  NS   ns2.swbell.net.
193.252.76.in-addr.arpa. IN  NS   ns1.swbell.net.
```

Which way you configure your BIND doesn't change this, as it wouldn't be queried anyway. Frankly, it's already how it should be: you aren't yet competent enough to manage your own DNS, as you don't meet the [Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements), including:

1. You only have one DNS server, both `ns1` and `ns2` pointing to the same IP address `76.252.193.233`.

   > **Minimum number of name servers**
   >  There must be at least two NS records listed in a delegation, and the hosts must not resolve to the
   > same IP address.
   >
   > **Network diversity**
   >  The name servers must be in at least two topologically separate networks. A network is defined as an origin
   > autonomous system in the BGP routing table. The requirement is
   > assessed through inspection of views of the BGP routing table.
2. The DNS for your domain isn't even working, as it misses `NS` records from the parent zone.
3. It seems you have zones for the subdomains, but not for the domain itself?!

   ```
   $ dig kosmoswebhosting.net SOA @76.252.193.233
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 9786

   $ dig ns1.kosmoswebhosting.net SOA @76.252.193.233 +short
   ns1.kosmoswebhosting.net. root.ns1.kosmoswebhosting.net. 2011071001 3600 1800 604800 86400

   $ dig ns2.kosmoswebhosting.net SOA @76.252.193.233 +short
   ns2.kosmoswebhosting.net. root.ns2.kosmoswebhosting.net. 2011071002 3600 1800 604800 86400
   ```

**I'd recommend paying the service fees & possibly ask them also host your forward DNS**, as they are professionals in this area. The hard way would be learning how DNS works, but it might be you'd rather like to concentrate on your core competences.